# Reading a content of SkyDrive file

Tags: javascript, web-applications, xmlhttprequest, onedrive

### What I have

I have  **WEB** application running in browser that has to access SkyDrive files. 
I use `WL.js` provided nice interface to access the file list for the current authenticated user:

```
   function openFromSkyDrive() {
        WL.fileDialog({
            mode: 'open',
            select: 'single'
        }).then(
        function (response) {

            var files = response.data.files;
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                log(file.name);
                WL.download({ "path": file.id + "/content" }, onDownloadFileCompleted).then(
                function (response) {
                   var r = response;
                },
                function (responseFailed) {
                  log("Error downloading file: " + responseFailed.error.message);
                });


                //TRIED TO USE SIMPLE GET CALL TOO, DIDN'T WORKED AS WELL
               /* var url = file.link;
                WL.api({ path: url,

                    method: "GET"
                }).then(
                     function (response) {
                         log("Downloaded : " + response.name + ", ID: " + response.id)
                     },
                    function (responseFailed) {
                        "Error calling API: " + responseFailed.error.message;
                    }
                ); */

            }
        },
       .....
    );
    }
```

Everything work nice and clean.

### Problem

When I use `WL.download` the download of the file starts in the browser so the **browser** loads the file, but what I need is to load the file content into my javascript, so **I can** handle content directly from my application.

Please note, that I've already tried to use `WL.api` method with `GET` and different paths (I tried all of the available in file object) and it failed: or it returns an error, or just nothing.

`WinJS` seems provide `XHR` call method, but I can not use it as I'm writing web applicaton and `WinJS` is for desktop use only.

### Question

How can I handle content of the downloaded/downloading file from skydrive ? Is it possible without running into manual frame creation and XHR call definition ?

Comment: I am facing the same problem at the moment. Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: no, actually I passed to DropBox like a cloud solution, that has way better documented JS support.

Comment: I think I found a solution: file.source returns the URL of the file ony Skydrive. The only problem here is that reading this with Javascript might not work due to cross site issues.

Comment: @Hyndrix: it's not an issue with dropbox JS api, I already used it and downloaded a data directly into the js code.

Comment: Yep, Dropbox is great - I am using it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WL.api method like this to create a link that will allow you to access the file:

```
WL.api({
    path: file.id + "/content",
    method: "GET"
}).then(
    function(response) {
        //URL will be in response.location, so load file content using jQuery or similar
        $.get(response.location, /* etc */);
    },
    function(err) {
        alert(err);
    }
);
```

Strangely, the URL returned by `response.location` does not require any auth - so you can email to someone else and they'll have access to the file.  This is REGARDLESS of whether the file is set to shared or not in OneDrive.  Seems odd to me from a security point of view, but I might be missing something.